# Problems with front-end uploads Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, upload, internal-server-error

Im having problems with users uploading videos to my website, The upload just times out and I get an internal 500 server error. Although uploading photos is fine?

I have my own server with 4GB of ram and my server is Apache

This the php.ini file i have create.

```
safe_mode = off;

upload_max_filesize = 3048mb;
post_max_size = 4000mb;
max_execution_time = 300;
```

Comment: which web server are you using? Nginx? Apache? etc..

Comment: Good question Joe, all i know is that its a performance server with 1and1